# AX7: Creating a method on a View using the extension method (bug?)

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax7, d3fo

**Edit:** The question is, why won't a display method on a `view` work?

I'm trying to use the extension method to create a display method on the `DirPartyPostalAddressView` and as far as I can tell, this might be an `AX7` bug or I'm doing it wrong. I'm on the latest AX7 with the recent update.

I'm using the method detailed here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mfp/2015/12/15/x-in-ax7-extension-methods/

I created a proof of concept `display method` for use on the view `DirPartyPostalAddressView` vs table `CustTable` to show the possible `bug`.

> **Extension class code:**
>
> ```
> static class MyClass_extension
> {
>     public static display NoYesId displayYesDirPartyPostalAddressView (DirPartyPostalAddressView _this)
>     {
>         return NoYes::Yes;
>     }
>
>     public static display NoYesId displayYesCustTable (CustTable _this)
>     {
>         return NoYes::Yes;
>     }
> }
> ```

I create an extension of the form `CustTable`, add a checkbox control to it, set the `DataSource = CustTable` and `DataMethod = MyClass_extension::displayYesCustTable` and this works correctly. (See screenshots)

[image: CodeChanges]

[image: Working image]

**The Issue:** I created an extension of the form `LogisticsPostalAddressGrid`, add a checkbox control to the grid, set the `DataSource = DirPartyPostalAddressView` and it does not compile. (See screenshot)

> **The error is:**
>
> `The data method
>   'MyClass_extension::displayYesDirPartyPostalAddressView' was not found
>   on the data source 'DirPartyPostalAddressView' or its base
>   table/view.`

[image: Non-compiling]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why won't the display method on the `view` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a bug and will be fixed in the next platform release.

See: https://connect.microsoft.com/site1321/feedback/details/3100997/data-methods-are-not-found-using-extension-method-on-views

Answer (score 0):

I think in you should be using a computed column on the view and forget about the display methods there.

Take a look at [this](https://ax.help.dynamics.com/en/wiki/data-entity-computed-columns-and-virtual-fields/#example-create-a-computed-field) in the AX help Wiki. I guess that for testing purposes it's enough if in the method for the computed column you just "return '1'" or "return true".

Comment: It's returning a symbol (icon/picture). I just made the example simple as a POC failure. I'll look this over and see if I can get away with a computed column though.